# When using 2P CRDT data structures (for example 2P-set), how do you free up space?

Tags: data-structures, computer-science, distributed-computing, crdt

2P-set allows to remove the elements from a set, but doesn't allow to free the space those removed elements take up. In fact, removal of an element consumes space, rather that frees it.
What's the algorithm to free up space for 2P structures?

I'm trying to understand for what problems can I use CRDT structures in practice. Without a way to free up space, the 2P CRDT structures seem to have a very limited use for the real world tasks.

Answer (score 3):

While I cannot speak for 2P-Set - since I still haven't figured out a practical use case for it. However usually we can apply few techniques:

1. **Compaction of metadata used by CRDT**: a lot of CRDTs where initially implemented with very simple design, and later on optimized to meet industry standards. Example of such can be `OR-Set` reimplemented on top of *dotted vector versions*. In this implementation you don't need to keep removed elements in memory: instead we can track added/removed elements using dots that could eventually be compressed into vector clocks. [Here](https://bartoszsypytkowski.com/optimizing-state-based-crdts-part-2/) I described this problem in more detail.
2. **Prunning** can be useful, once some of the replicas are no longer needed, eg. because we reduced a number of nodes or these nodes are no longer available. In such case, we can merge the payload with metadata as if it was produced by another replica. Example: *given `G-Counter` represented with map `{A:1,B:2,C:1}` and a dead node `B` (which can no longer increment its state), we could prune it by merging `B`'s entry into shape `{A:3,C:1}`*, therefore reducing its size while still preserving the correct value. The problem is that prunning algorithm must guarantee, that all replicas must converge into this decision independently.

Comment: OR-Set seems to be the same as 2P-Set, but I have to confirm this.

Comment: No, 2P-Set is add-once/remove-once (which means, that once you remove an element, you cannot add it again). ORSet or Observed Remove Sets allows for a multiple additions/removals with an arbitrary action taken in case of conflicting updates.

Comment: A practical use of 2P-Sets would be maintaining a set of elements associated with randomly generated globally unique IDs. For example, rows in a table. It would be possible to recreate a removed row with the exact same values, because the new ID would practically be guaranteed different. I'm not familiar with dotted vectors, but the way I see it, even if they mitigate the growth by encoding CRDTs more efficiently, tombstones could still grow indefinitely over time, even if the value itself remains constant. Also, the strategy for pruning nodes in counters doesn't really help with tombstones.